# jQuery Navigation Menu - Sub Menu Disappearing on MouseOut

Tags: jquery, navigation, mouseout, mouseenter

I am developing my own jQuery Navigation Menu and have run into a bit of a problem as the sub-menus disappear as soon as the focus is taken away from the selection on the main navigation menu. I know there must be a simple solution to this but I've spent hours on this and figured it was time for some help.

Here is the code below:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('.myMenu li ul').hide(); //hide all sub menus

        $('.myMenu > li').mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).fadeIn("fast");
        });

        $('.myMenu > li').mouseout(function() {
            $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
<ul class="myMenu">
    <li><a href="#">Main 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Main 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 9</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Main 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>  
    <li><a href="#">Main 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Main 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Main 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Main 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Main 8</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Any help would be gladly appreciated!

Comment: `mouseleave` is the opposite of `mouseenter`, not `mouseout`.  [The `.hover()` method](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) combines `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` and works much better than `mouseover` and `mouseout` which tend to be flaky about how you move/hover/etc.  It may or may not solve this particular issue but it will be less headaches in the long run.

Comment: I haven't been able to make the hover method work. Must be missing something!

Comment: [This is your existing code in a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zr5ca/2/) which clearly demonstrates your problem.  See my answer below which solves the issue by using the `.hover()` method instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is merely your exact code above converted into the correct format for [the `.hover()` method](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) which conveniently combines `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` into one method.

```
$('.myMenu > li').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).fadeIn("fast");
}, 
    function() {
        $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
});
```

It seems to solve the problem as you described.  "Main 2" and "Main 3" stay open when you're within their corresponding sub-menus.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zr5ca/1

Answer (score 1):

Here's what i did to make your problem somewhat easier. http://jsfiddle.net/raynesax/GWvVj/5/

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't seem to work at all then. You are right though it should make it easier.

Comment: Rajat, if you're going to post an answer in a jsFiddle, at least make sure it does something.